# How to access war file modified date?

Tags: java, tomcat

In order to show the user last modified date of the web application in Java, I need to access the war file's last modified date property under Tomcat. I don't have an accurate war file path, because the path is different for all users of application. My goal is to reach war file and return is last modified date. How can I do this?

Comment: better create the build date during build and the build version, no need to access the war file,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add build date into META-INF/MANIFEST.MF and parse from there. Using file creation date is not really good way to version your application.